# Yii. Checking url before redirecting to prevent attack

Tags: url, redirect, yii, sanitize

I have **$returnUrl** var from **Form** with controller/action in it:

```
<?=CHtml::hiddenField('returnUrl', 
    Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request)
);?>
```

In controller i have something like this:

```
$returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->getPost('returnUrl');
$returnUrl = array($returnUrl);
$this->redirect($returnUrl);
```

But it also work then i change **$returnUrl** from **controller/action** to external site url. Ex: if i put **http://google.com** to **$_POST['returnUrl']** instead of **site/index** yii redirect me to **/http://google.com** without any errors.

What is the best way to check **$returnUrl** before redirecting? How i can compare **$returnUrl** with my routes or controllers/actions?

Now i do next:

```
$returnUrl = Utils::sanitizeReturnUrl($returnUrl);    
...
class Utils 
{
    public static function sanitizeReturnUrl($returnUrl)
    {
        if (!preg_match('~^([-a-z0-9_]+|[-a-z0-9_]+/[-a-z0-9_]+)+$~i', $returnUrl))
        {
            $returnUrl = Yii::app()->homeUrl;
        }

        return $returnUrl;
    }
 }
```

But may be exists more appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to parse your returnUrl and remove the scheme (`http://` or `https://`) and other insecure stuff.

```
<?php
$returnUrl = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
$returnUrl = sanitizeReturnUrl($returnUrl);
echo $returnUrl; 
/**
 * now you got:
 * hostname/path?arg=value#anchor
 */

function sanitizeReturnUrl ($url)
{
    $urlArray = parse_url($url);
    $url = $urlArray['host'] . $urlArray['path'] . '?' . $urlArray['query'] . '#' .     $urlArray['fragment'];
    return $url;
}
```